# NSDateComponents: Get nearest future date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I am creating date components and using the largest unit to display
For example:

- 1 day 23 hour 2 minute -> 2 days to go (as hour is close to next day
  +1 day value)
- 1 day 10 hour 53 minute -> 1 day to go
- 0 day 10 hour 50 minute -> 11 hours to go (as minutes are close to next hour    +1    hour value)

I'm using below logic to create components

```
NSCalendar *const calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *const components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay |
                                                       NSCalendarUnitHour |
                                                       NSCalendarUnitMinute)
                                                 fromDate:[NSDate date]
                                                   toDate:date
                                                  options:NSCalendarWrapComponents];
if components.day {return components.day}
if components.hour {return components.hour}
if component.minute {return component.minute}
```

But above code returns below

- 1 day 23 hour 2 minute -> 1 day to go
- 1 day 10 hour 53 minute -> 1 day to go
- 0 day 10 hour 50 minute -> 10 hours to go

Is there any formatter options that can be used to get rounded up day/hour based upon value of hour/minutes after that?

I know I can check for value of hour if day is present and +1 the day but i'm looking if theres anything supported from iOS

Comment: You need `NSDateComponentsFormatter`

Comment: I tried NSDateComponentsFormatter's properties but was not able to achieve the round up behaviour. Can you be more specific about which properties should i set?
Maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You need more logic eg if hours > 12 then increase day etc ...

Comment: `.maximumUnitCount = 1`